# Need to place strings in different txt files depending on their first letter (A to Z)

Tags: c

So, I've been doing this school project for a while now and one of its many parts consists on asking the user for a word input, taking their input and placing it in the file that corresponds to its first letter. **CREATING VOIDS IS NOT ALLOWED**

Ex. Input: "Orange" --> O.txt
Input: "Gerald" --> G.txt

I don't understand how I'm supposed to compare the filename with the first letter of the word.
Please, Gods of C, help me out.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is:

```c
#include<stdio.h>
void string_to_file(const char * str) {
    char buffer[100] = {};             // create a template file

    fprintf("%c.txt", str[0]);         // put the first letter of the
                                       // string in the first letter of
                                       // the file name
    
    FILE * f = fopen(buffer, "a");     // open the file, the "a" mean
                                       // append

    fprintf(f, "%s\n", str);           // print in the file your string
                                       // and a new line

    fclose(f);                         // close file
}
```

Comment: If you make `buffer` a `const` array, you cannot modify it with `buffer[0] = str[0];`

Answer (score 0):

It's not as difficult as you may think. First of all, you don't necessarily have to compare anything at all.

Lets say you have the following function:
`void writeInput(const char* input)`. What you'll basically want to do, is take the first letter of the input, place it in another string, add the `.txt` extention and use that as a file path.
The most simple way would be to initialize the string with such a path to begin with, and then replace the first letter of it the the input's first letter.

Here is a simple example:

```
void writeInput(const char* input)
{
   char path[] = " .txt"; //space will be replaces with first letter
   path[0] = input[0]; //assuming input is not empty

   FILE* file = fopen(path, "w");
   if (!file)
   {
      printf("Error openning file");
      exit(1);
   }
   fputs(input, file); //writes input to file
   fclose(file);
}
```

Please note that using `exit(1)` is probably not good practice, but this is just an example.

If you didn't know that you'll always use just one letter before the `.txt` extention, I would recommend using `strcat`, which is used to concatinate strings together.

Comment: Consider opening the file for appending with `fopen(path, "a");`